# Too many usestate - Reacct

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I am finding myselft writing multiple setState decalrations in React functional Component.

```
const [option1, setOption1] = useState(false);
const [option2, setOption2] = useState(false);
const [option3, setOption3] = useState(false);
const [option4, setOption4] = useState(false);
const [option5, setOption5] = useState(false);
```

In vue I can do

```
const option = ref(true);
```

Is there something similar in react where I can just create a reactive variable without usestate or a clever use of usestate where I can combine what is esentially just local variables?

Comment: What are your options used for? There's nothing inherently wrong with having lots of state variables (and most methods of combining them actually cause more issues than they solve)

Comment: If you think you are state is getting complex, then you can look to use `useReducer` hook. Another option to define the state as array and work based on indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your code setup to work with these multiple state variables, it shouldn't be a problem to just combine these into an array. You are not working with an index state variable right now, so you should not need one with this array I suppose (but I don't know the rest of your code).

Just try this:

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState(new Array(5).fill(false))
```

To edit this you can create a shallow copy and update the value you want and then update the state variable.

```
options_copy = [...options]
options_copy[0] = true
setOptions(options_copy)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that's a pretty nice idea!